# UIButton in second View Controller - Touch Up Inside not working (Touch Down does)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have created a new project in XCode and used the new Storyboard-feature to create two different View Controllers.

The first View Controller is attached to the main files (**ViewController.h, Viewcontroller.m**). The second View Controller is attached to it's own set of .h/.m files (**NewUserController.m/.h**)

Now for the problem which I havent been able to find a solution for in the last hours;

I have added a button the second view controller and attached the button to an IBAction (**verifyNumber**). When I attach the '**Touched Up Inside**' event the IBAction is never fired. However, when I attach the '**Touch Down**' everything works fine..

Both View Controller's have got the 'user interaction enabled' selected and apart from the button the second view controller doesn't contain any other elements. Also, my manual performSegueWithIdentifier is working (switch from view1 to view2).

Can anyone spot where it has gone wrong?

The code:

ViewController.m

```
- (void)firstStartup {

    // Future use for getting userID

    // Switch to loginview
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueLogin" sender:self];       

}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Fire firstStartup
    [self firstStartup];

}
```

NewUserController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewUserController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inputNumber;

- (IBAction)backgroundTap;
//- (IBAction)verifyNumber;

- (IBAction)verifyNumber:(id)sender;

@end
```

NewUserController.m

```
#import "NewUserController.h"

@implementation NewUserController
@synthesize inputNumber;


// Collect User data & Start Request
- (IBAction)verifyNumber:(id)sender; {

    inputNumber.text = @"testing";

}

- (IBAction)backgroundTap {

    [inputNumber resignFirstResponder];    

}
```

**UPDATE**

Because of the response of NJones I have tested some more and deleted the gesturerecognizer I had present on the second view. After deleting this recognizer the UIButton works with all events (Touched Up Inside).

Does the recognizer somehow block any 'tap' events to overlaying objects (such as the UIButton)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a few thoughts,

1) Why do you have:

```
    - (IBAction)backgroundTap;
    //- (IBAction)verifyNumber;

    - (IBAction)verifyNumber:(id)sender;
```

There is a difference between `verifyNumber` and `verifyNumber:(id)sender` and they can both exist at the same time, and both can be connected in the `nib`.

2) Are you using any UIGestureRecoginzers on the view at all?

3) Is this button a custom button or subclass of UIButton?

4) (I truly don't think this will help solve your problem it's just good practice, and I'm already typing :)) Using a view property to check if a method was called is inconclusive at best. Try putting a log statement in the `IBAction` method like So:

```
- (IBAction)verifyNumber:(id)sender; {
    NSLog(@"verifyNumber:");
    inputNumber.text = @"testing";
}
```

Comment: 1) I had commented out the first IBAction to test if there would be any difference when passing the sender. Currently the only function (deleted the rest) is: - (IBAction)verifyNumber:(id)sender { - And this one is also connected to the button action (dubbel checked)

2) Yes there is, I have added a gesture recognizer to the view to detect a tap -> This activates the (IBAction)backgroundTap -> Purpouse: hides the keyboard on tap on view

3) subClass of UIButton

4) I have added some logging to the function to log the input value, which is better off course

===

Unfortunately no difference..

Comment: After your response I have tested some more (deleted the gesture recognizer of the view) and now the button works as 'advertised' (Touched Up Inside fires the function)